# How to move the expand/collapse group columns to the right?

Tags: google-sheets

There are two spreadsheets with columns being grouped.
In the first the grouping looks pretty standard - note that the +/- control is on the left of grouped columns:

[image: first spreadsheet]

And in the second - I accidentally made the +/- control appearing on the right:
[image: second spreadsheet]

I don't realize the repro steps for the second variant. What happened and how can I undo that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the line and choose "move button to the left" (or to the right).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no grouped columns yet and are trying to group Column A, first create a temporary group of other columns that aren't at the left of the sheet.

Then right-click the [-] button and choose "Move +/- button to the right".

Then you can create your group of Column A and then delete your temporary column group elsewhere.